# How to use "BinaryString.uncons()" but with a type distinct from Word8?

Tags: haskell, binary-data

I have a binary string. I want to split it into head and tail. The close candidate is from `bytestring` is:

```
uncons :: ByteString -> Maybe (Word8, ByteString)
```

But I want to split it such that the head would be, say, of type `Word16` instead of `Word8`. Or `Word32`. Or anything else.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `take`, `splitAt`, etc, to extract the desired number of bytes, and if that succeeds, then apply whatever decoding you want to them.

Comment: What should happen if the `ByteString` has only one byte?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what I define it to be

Comment: Would the question actually be substantially different if you picked any one of the sensible possible answers to that clarification?

Comment: Note that this question was flagged and nominated for removal for being off-topic.  I don't believe the question is off-topic, but this comment thread among @DanielWagner and others sure doesn't make much sense to me.  Were there more comments here that were subsequently removed, or something?  Could this be cleaned up?

Comment: @DonHatch I don't recall any comments that don't currently appear. If you skip tarin's comments, the comment thread looks pretty reasonable/understandable/relevant to me -- or at least, no worse than is standard for SO. As for tarin's comments, well, I'm coming to the opinion that they are being intentionally incendiary/confusing, though to what end I can only guess. It certainly doesn't seem to me like an effective way to get volunteers to help you more.

Comment: @DanielWagner I also didn't follow what "that clarification" referred to in your comment "Would the question actually be substantially different if you picked any one of the sensible possible answers to that clarification?", so that's why I thought I might be reading it out of context.  In any case, I see what you mean, this seems to be a rather troll-ish situation and I'm losing interest, so I'll disengage now.  Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are many deserialization libraries available. For one that sounds like it is a particularly close match to your mental model, check out [binary's `Get`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.8.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#g:7). It is not really in scope to give a Big List of all the available ones, but a quick search on Hackage should give you many other choices to consider.

Comment: what libraries? there's only that one library that's decent and nothing more

Comment: Sorry, but you can't trick me into making a Big List, even in this roundabout way. Do your own legwork.